# Delay within a timer (what is the correct approach)

Tags: c, timer, delay

I'm in a pickle regarding concepts relating to timers. How can I can I operate a "delay" inside a timer? This is the best way I can frame the question knowing full well what I'm trying to do is nonsense. The objective is: I wish to test the pinState condition 2 times (once initially and then 4 seconds later) but this all needs to happen periodically (hence a timer).

The platform is NodeMCU running a WiFi (ESP8266 chip) and coding done inside Arduino IDE.

```
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

BlynkTimer timer;
char auth[] = "x"; //Auth code sent via Email
char ssid[] = "x"; //Wifi name
char pass[] = "x";  //Wifi Password
int flag=0;

void notifyOnFire()
{
  int pinState = digitalRead(D1);
  if (pinState==0 && flag==0) {
    delay(4000);
    int pinStateAgain = digitalRead(D1);
    if (pinStateAgain==0) {
        Serial.println("Alarm has gone off");
        Blynk.notify("House Alarm!!!");
        flag=1;
      }
  }
  else if (pinState==1)
  {
    flag=0;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  pinMode(D1,INPUT_PULLUP);
  timer.setInterval(1000L,notifyOnFire); 
}

void loop()
{
  //Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();
}
```

Comment: You could add a variable to keep track of when the event happens. Then next time it happens, compare current time to last time.

Comment: Can you add details about the platform you're targetting?

Comment: You could easily do this in C with something like UNIX timestamp comparison, but you are using a proprietary library that you haven't said anything about.

Comment: Set up another timer which runs 4 seconds later

Comment: Added additional platform details

Comment: Save the state and set a second timer callback for 4 seconds later.Then you can compare to the saved state.

Comment: a 4 second delay in an interrupt handler is VERY BAD design.  Suggest restarting the timer for 4 seconds.  Should probably keep track, inside the timer interrupt handler, via a static variable, indicating if the current time span is for 1 second or 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

an easy fix would be to set the periodicity of the timer to be 4000L `timer.setInterval(4000L,notifyOnFire);` and in `notifyOnFire` use a static variable and toggle its value whenever `notifyOnFire` is called

```
void notifyOnFire()
{
  static char state = 0;
  if( state == 0)
  {
    /* Write here the code you need to be executed before the 4 sec delay */
    state = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Write here the code you need to be executed after the 4 sec delay */
    state = 0;
  }
}
```

The nice thing about static variables is that they are initialized only once at compile time and they retain their values after the scope of code changes (In this case function `notifyOnFire` exits).